# Is there a Linux equivalent of SetWindowPos?

Tags: c, linux, windows

A while ago I wrote a script in C that used the Windows API functions EnumWindows, SetWindowPos and SetForegroundWindow to automatically arrange windows (by title) in a particular layout that I commonly wanted.

Are there Linux equivalents for these functions? I will be using Kubuntu, so KDE-specific and/or Ubuntu-specific solutions are fine.

Comment: You might want to use a tiling wm along with KDE: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/KDE_and_awesome or http://blog.frozen-zone.org/2010/01/kde4-with-xmonad/

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is either in the window manager itself (if yours supports extensions) or with the protocols and hints designed to support "pagers" (pager = any non-window-manager process that does window organization or navigation things).

The EWMH spec includes a _NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW designed for use by pagers. http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2731465

Raw Xlib or Xcb is pretty rough but there's a library called libwnck specifically designed to do the kind of thing you're talking about. (I wrote the original library long ago but it's been maintained by others forever.) Even if you don't use it, read the code to see how to do stuff. KDE may have an equivalent with KDE-style APIs I'm not sure.

There should be no need to use anything KDE or GNOME or distribution specific since the needed stuff is all spelled out in EWMH. That said, for certain window managers doing this as an extension may be easier than writing a separate app.

Using old school X calls directly can certainly be made to work but there are lots of details to handle there that require significant expertise if you want to iron out all the bugs and corner cases, in my opinion, so using a WM extension API or pager library would be my advice.

Answer (score 3):

@andrewdotn has a fine answer there but you can do this old school as well fairly simply by walking the tree starting at the root window of the display using XQueryTree and fetching the window name with XFetchName then moving it with XMoveWindow. Here is an example that will list all the windows and if any are called 'xeyes' they get moved to the top left. Like most X programs, there is more to it and this should probably be calling XGetWindowProperty to fetch the _NET_WM_NAME extended window manager property but the example works ok as a starter. Compile with `gcc -Wall -g -o demo demo.c -lX11`

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int
EnumWindows(Display *display, Window window, int depth)
{
    Window parent, *children;
    unsigned int count = 0;
    int r = 1, n = 0;
    char *name = NULL;

    XFetchName(display, window, &name);
    for (n = 0; n < depth; ++n) putchar(' ');
    printf("%08x %s\n", (int)window, name?name:"(null)");
    if (name && strcmp("xeyes", name) == 0) {
        XMoveWindow(display, window, 5, 5);
    }
    if (name) XFree(name);

    if (XQueryTree(display, window, &window, &parent, &children, &count) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: XQueryTree error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (n = 0; r && n < count; ++n) {
        r = EnumWindows(display, children[n], depth+1);
    }
    XFree(children);
    return r;
}

int
main(int argc, char *const argv[])
{
    Display *display = NULL;

    if ((display = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: cannot connect to X server\n");
        return 1;
    }

    EnumWindows(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using the X Windows protocol. It’s a very low-level protocol so it will take some work. You can use `xcb_query_tree` to find the window to operate on, and then move it with `xcb_configure_window`. [This page](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/windowcontextandmanipulation/) gives some details on how to do it. There’s a [basic tutorial](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/) on using the library those functions come from, but you’ll probably want to Google for a better one.

It may seem daunting, but it’s not too bad. Here’s a 50-line C program that will move all your xterms 10px to the right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>

void handle(xcb_connection_t* connection, xcb_window_t window) {

    xcb_query_tree_reply_t *tree = xcb_query_tree_reply(connection,
        xcb_query_tree(connection, window), NULL);
    xcb_window_t *children = xcb_query_tree_children(tree);

    for (int i = 0;  i < xcb_query_tree_children_length(tree); i++) {

        xcb_get_property_reply_t *class_reply = xcb_get_property_reply(
            connection,
            xcb_get_property(connection, 0, children[i], XCB_ATOM_WM_CLASS,
                XCB_ATOM_STRING, 0, 512), NULL);
        char* class = (char*)xcb_get_property_value(class_reply);
        class[xcb_get_property_value_length(class_reply)] = '\0';

        if (!strcmp(class, "xterm")) {
            /* Get geometry relative to parent window */
            xcb_get_geometry_reply_t* geom = xcb_get_geometry_reply(
                connection,
                xcb_get_geometry(connection, window),
                NULL);

            /* Move 10 pixels right */
            uint32_t values[] = {geom->x + 10};
            xcb_configure_window(connection, children[i],
                XCB_CONFIG_WINDOW_X, values);
        }

        /* Recurse down window tree */
        handle(connection, children[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    xcb_connection_t *connection;
    const xcb_setup_t *setup;

    connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    setup = xcb_get_setup(connection);
    xcb_screen_iterator_t screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup);
    handle(connection, screen.data->root);

    return 0;
}
```

There’s no error-checking or memory management, and what it can do is pretty limited. But it should be straightforward to update into a program that does what you want, or to turn it into a general-purpose helper program by adding command-line options to specify which windows to operate on and which operations to perform on them.

Comment: @rubenvb  
If you have a better answer, by all means post it, and I will upvote your answer and delete this one. But I don’t think you’d be resorting to insults if you did have a better answer.

Comment: +1 for providing a modern XCB example, it's one thing for legacy code to keep using Xlib ... but new code should really be using the modern methods. Or better yet, going without X completely, but that wouldn't make sense as the OP was specifically about X.

Comment: I agree with TechZilla, because of all the outdated code, new programmers end up doing their stuff initially in xlib, and then realize they have to switch to xcb because of all the threading etc these days. I'm in that situation now, redoing all my work with xcb, as i would get unexplainable behavior with xlib. Thanks for this example it helps so much!

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are not looking specifically for a solution in code, but rather in a desktop environment, you need to take a look at one of the window managers that handle the window placement in such a desktop environment.

1. KDE's [KWin's Window Attributes](http://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules_Window_Attributes/en#Size_.26_Position)
2. Compiz (GNOME) has "Window Rules" and "Place Windows" in the CompizConfig Settings Manager application. See e.g. [here](http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/create-window-placement-rule-using-compiz-fusion-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/)
3. Openbox seems a lot harder to get right, although they link to a GUI tool at the bottom of [this page](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help%3aApplications).

The problem with using X directly is that X in itself knows nothing about your desktop environment (panels, shortcuts, etc.) and you'll have to compensate manually.

After googling for this, I'm surprised KDE is the only one that has a simple way to do this.